# Laravel autocomplete search questions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, autocomplete, laravel-5.1

I am working on online shop that has categories  page and in accordance of the category that is chosen products page is displayed .
I want to create an autocomplete search field that will be available in those 2 pages that will show products only , once that match the search.

Where should I create my search field?How my route should look?What view should I return? I would appreciate very much even farther instructions of creating autocomplete search field. Thank you

Comment: There are many different ways you can do this. You can use premade libraries or make one yourself using ajax requests. It all depends on your requirements.

Comment: How about the first 2 questions ? Not sure about that .Should I create the search field in both pages? How my route should look?

Answer (score 0):

if you create the search field in both pages you code should look like this:

**the search field:**

```
<input type="text" name="search" value="" id="search">
```

**your route:**

```
Route::post('/search', 'SomeController@searchFunction')->name('search');
```

**and your search function in the controller**

```
class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function searchFunction(Request $request){
        return CategoryClass::where('name', 'like', '%'.$request->search.'%')->get();
    }

}
```

then you can create a main.js file por example with you ajax call and include it in both blade pages

**the ajax call can be something like this:**

```
$("#search").keyup(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('search') }}",
        type: "post",
        data: $("search").serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            //do something
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps